# How can I change my default physical path of localhost in xampp?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, iis-7.5, wampserver

[
-Requested URL is the path from htdocs in xampp folder !

-On the other hand, Physical path is showing the path of the directories of wamp server. I unistalled wampserver but still it is showing this root as directories][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHRXo.png)

**I unistalled wampserver but still it is showing this root as directories and I also changed my httpd.config directories of xampp to htdocs of xampp**

Now, How can I change the **Physical Path** to xampp htdocs directories location.

Comment: Did you try to install it on an external drive for the reinstall?

Comment: What are you trying to use as a web server XAMPP or IIS? If you are not trying to use IIS then uninstall it

Comment: I have done with the solution ! It worked for me ! :)
Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score -1):

I have found how to change the default Physical Path in Xampp.

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open run.
2. type **cmd** then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. type **cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv** in your command prompt then press ENTER.
4. type **C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set vdir "MySite/" -physicalPath:"C:\xampp\htdocs"**

You have to replace your directories in the place of "C:\xampp\htdocs" .

[Solved]